# Retrieve the Magento product data from Apache Solr

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, solr

Folks,

I am fairly new to Magento.

I intend to use Magento for a purely search driven solution where in the products will be primarily be displayed upon search by product name.

My search infrastucture is Solr based with an existing index in place , I need to know if I can source the product data solely from an index in Apache Solr and if the products can be displayed only when a search is made by the product name with in the Magento app.

I have seen posts where apparently the search with in Magento is supported by Solr, but I was not sure if the product data can be solely sourced from a Solr index.

## EDIT

I have been asked to clarify , when I say source data from Solr , I mean all the attributes  for a product , like name , price, description, images(urls) , etc.

I have a solr index which has all the attributes of a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be a little more specific? Yes, it is possible to only set the product name to be indexed by SOLR. Give it a score of 5 and disable the rest from being searched.

But please, elaborate, as I do not fully understand your question.

**EDIT AFTER ELABORATION**

Yes, what you say is possible. However the image URLs are not possible to be indexed AFAIK. You can however index any other data that you like.

SOLR will give you back a result based on your search; which will be xml or json. From there you can parse the data in PHP.

Why not just use the SKU/ID and then get the data with the Magento functionalities?

Hope this helps you a bit...

Comment: @user1965449 see my edit :)

Comment: Thanks , what Solr client API PHP based do you suggest to let me use the latest and greatest Solr, I know that the official Magento Solr support is up until Solr 3.6 , I am assuming you are suggesting custom development , I do not have the SKU/ID for all the products.And also the image URLs are already live and are present in the Solr index as stored fields and not as indexes fields. Thanks again  for your help!

Comment: @user1965449 Solarium will help you. Please accept my answer if you are satisfied :)